# Defining Reusable and Easily Editable Keywords

Tags: macros, keywords

I am writing a paper in which I still haven't made all the stylistic choices. That is I haven't decided which long words I want to abbreviate and how I want to abbreviate them, if the author of the paper is a "me", a "we", a "the author" or the "authors" etc. So what I want to do is define a few keywords that will be reused many times.

I want to at the top of my document do something along the lines of `\newcommand{\auth}{we}` and whenever I write `\auth{}` in my document the word "we" should show up. Now, the more seasoned of you will notice that what I am describing here will actually do what I want it to so on to the real question.

What I really want to do is link a word in the english dictionary to a command and when passing an argument to that command being able to slightly change its output. So for instance if I define `\auth{}` to spit out "we" I want `\auth{upper}` to spit out "We" instead. I would also like to be able to get possessive forms from it such as "Ours" and "ours" by calling `\auth{upper, possessive}`, `\auth{possessive}` or something similar. What would be the best way to achieve this? Can I create a dictionary of sorts or what do you recommend?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I've tried. BTW, it only works in LuaLaTeX:

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
dofile(kpse.find_file("l-lpeg.lua"))
dofile(kpse.find_file("util-sto.lua"))
dofile(kpse.find_file("util-prs.lua"))
Pronouns = {
    ["formal"] = {
        ["possessive"] = "ours",
        ["nominative"] = "we",
        ["oblique"] = "us"
    },
    ["informal"] = {
        ["possessive"] = "mine",
        ["nominative"] = "I",
        ["oblique"] = "me"
    }
}
function Auth(keywords)
    local dummy = utilities.parsers.settings_to_array(keywords)
    for i,v in ipairs(dummy) do
        if Pronouns[dummy[i]] ~= nil then result = Pronouns[dummy[i]] end
    end
    for i,v in ipairs(dummy) do
        if result[dummy[i]] ~= nil then result = result[dummy[i]] end
    end
    return result
end
function Upper(string)
    return unicode.utf8.upper(unicode.utf8.sub(string,1,1))..unicode.utf8.sub(string,2,utf8.len(string))
end
\end{luacode*}
\def\auth#1{\directlua{tex.print(Auth("#1"))}}
\def\Auth#1{\directlua{tex.print(Upper(Auth("#1")))}}
\begin{document}
\auth{oblique,informal} \Auth{formal,possessive}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This was surprisingly complex, but here is a solution working with any TeX*

```
\begingroup
\catcode`!=11 % for private macros
\endlinechar=-1
\catcode`\^^M=12 \catcode`\^^?=12\relax
\gdef\!stop{^^?}
\gdef\!fi{\fi}
\newtoks\!before \newtoks\!after

% some convenient shorthands
\gdef\!csnm#1{\csname#1\endcsname} 
\gdef\!ecsnm#1#2{\expandafter#1\csname#2\endcsname}

% the main command sets up the catcodes for reading in
% the definitions of the second argument
\gdef\newvarcommand#1{
  \begingroup\catcode`\^^M=12 \catcode`\^^?=12\relax
  {\escapechar=-1 \xdef\!name{\string#1}}
  \!ecsnm\newtoks{toks:\!name}
  \gdef#1##1{
    {\escapechar=-1 \xdef\!name{\string#1}}
    \begingroup
    \!processnextkey##1,^^?,
    \!ecsnm\the{toks:\!name}
    \!result
    \endgroup
  }
  \!newvarcommand
}

% for each modifier in the argument, set the corresponding
% conditional true
\gdef\!processnextkey#1,{\def\arg{#1}
  \ifx\!stop\arg\else
    \ifx\empty\arg\def\!key{default}\else\def\!key{#1}\fi
    \!ecsnm\ifx{ifkey:\!name:\!key}\relax
      \errmessage{Unknown key \!key\space for command \!name}
    \else\!csnm{key:\!name:\!key true}\fi
  \expandafter\!processnextkey\fi
}

% here we read the argument line by line
\gdef\!newvarcommand#1{\!getnext#1^^M^^?^^M}
\gdef\!getnext#1^^M{\def\arg{#1} 
  \ifx\!stop\arg\endgroup\else
  \ifx\empty\arg\else\!parse#1^^M\fi
  \expandafter\!getnext\fi
}

% for each entry, new conditionals are created to test whether a
% modifier is present or not, and a token list containing the
% conditionals and the word to be printed is appended to the
% token list read by the command to be defined
\gdef\!parse#1:#2^^M{\!before={}\!after={}\def\arg{#1}
  \ifx\empty\arg
    {\globaldefs=1 \!ecsnm\newif{ifkey:\!name:default}}
    \!before=\expandafter{\csname ifkey:\!name:default\endcsname}
    \!after=\expandafter{\!fi}
  \else\!setupnextkey#1,^^?,\fi
  \edef\!addtoks{\!ecsnm\the{toks:\!name}
    \the\!before\def\noexpand\!result{#2}\the\!after}
  \global\!csnm{toks:\!name}=\expandafter{\!addtoks}
}

% creating \newifs for each modifier
\gdef\!setupnextkey#1,{\def\arg{#1}
  \ifx\!stop\arg\else
    {\globaldefs=1 \!ecsnm\newif{ifkey:\!name:#1}}
    \!before=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\expandafter
      \expandafter\!before\!csnm{ifkey:\!name:#1}}
    \!after=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\!after\!fi}
  \expandafter\!setupnextkey\fi
}
\endgroup
```

You can then define your "dictionary" as follows:

```
\newvarcommand\auth{
  :we
  upper:We
  possessive:ours
  upper,possessive:Ours
}
```

In each line, you write the comma-separated words that you want to use as arguments, and then after a colon the word that should appear. The default value can be specified with either `:val` or `default:val`. **Important:** The entries should occur in the order of increasing number of specifiers (i.e., you should have all one-word entries first, then the ones with two comma-separated words, then three and so on), otherwise you might get incorrect results.

```
\auth{} \auth{default} % these two are the same, "we"
\auth{upper} % "We"
\auth{possessive} % "ours"
\auth{upper,possessive} \auth{possessive,upper} % both "Ours"
\auth{lower} % this gives an "Unknown key" error
```

Let me explain for the `upper,possessive:Ours` line how the code works. Basically when the line is read, it first creates conditionals `\ifkey:auth:upper` and `\ifkey:auth:possessive`. Then, a token list

```
\ifkey:auth:upper
  \ifkey:auth:possessive
    \def\!result{Ours}
  \fi
\fi
```

is constructed and appended to a token list named `\toks:auth`. If you use `\auth{upper,possessive}`, the arguments are read and the corresponding conditionals `\ifkey:auth:upper` and `ifkey:auth:possessive` are set to true, the `toks:auth` token list is unpacked and `\!result` is printed.

---

*It assumes a non-outer `\newif` though, like in LaTeX, but for plain TeX some adaptations would be necessary.